# Nuxt.js double link after refresh

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When it generates production code width 'npm run generate' i have error.

In this website http://vue.wmcreation.pl/about

when i refresh page nuxt add to boostrap nav link /about/about.

```
     <b-navbar toggleable="md">

          <b-navbar-toggle target="nav_collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>

          <b-navbar-brand :to="{ path: '/' }">#jwcreation</b-navbar-brand>

          <b-collapse is-nav id="nav_collapse">

            <b-navbar-nav class="center">

              <b-nav-item :to="{ path: '/' }">home</b-nav-item>
              <b-nav-item :to="{ path: 'about' }">about</b-nav-item>
            </b-navbar-nav>

            <!-- Right aligned nav items -->
            <b-navbar-nav class="right">
              <b-nav-item :to="{ path: 'test' }">hello@jwcreation.pl</b-nav-item>

            </b-navbar-nav>

          </b-collapse>
        </b-navbar>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code for that nav?

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should [edit] your original question to add additional information.

Comment: I'm edit post and add my navbar code :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `about` path must be absolute, otherwise it will accumulate with the current path :

```
<b-nav-item :to="{ path: '/about' }">about</b-nav-item>
```

---

Another way is to define your about link by the name page convention

```
<b-nav-item :to="{ name: 'about' }">about</b-nav-item>
```

*eg.*
`pages/test.vue` => `name: 'test'`
`pages/parent/child.vue` => `name: 'parent-child'`
`pages/parent/yolo/index.vue` => `name: 'parent-yolo'`